# Tracking when a patient might not have medicine

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I've been stuck on this a bit, and I could use some insight from the community.  Let's say that due to unusual circumstances, a patient receives a medicine on an irregular schedule:

```
Patient_Receiving_Schedule <- tibble(Medicine_Received = c(ymd("2019-01-01"), ymd("2019-01-20"), ymd("2019-02-01"), ymd("2019-06-01"), ymd("2019-06-15")),
                                        Days_of_Medicine_Received = c(30,30,30,30,30))
```

At some points, the patient will have excess medicine on hand from the prior shipment(s), and at some other points, the patient will have none or be overdue because it's been too long between shipments.  The ideal output is something like this:

```
Patient_Receiving_Schedule <- tibble(Medicine_Received = c(ymd("2019-01-01"), ymd("2019-01-20"), ymd("2019-02-01"), ymd("2019-06-01"), ymd("2019-05-15")),
                                        Days_of_Medicine_Received = c(30,30,30,30,30),
                                        Days_of_Medicine_Available = c(30,41,59,30,46),
                                        Notes = c("","","","Patient was 31 days overdue for medication",""))
```

The Days_of_Medicine_Available is sort of like a cumulative sum across Medicine_Received dates vs Days_of_Medicine_Received, but with rules because there isn't any point in summing negative values for Days_of_Medicine_Available.

Is there a way to do this with a lag() call and some logic around the cumsum value of Days of Medicine Available?

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a logic that if a medicine is not received for `x` number of days after the previous shipment then we need to reset `Days_of_Medicine_Available` calculation?

If yes, then you can use the following with `x = 30` for this example but you can actually set it to any value.

```
library(dplyr)

Patient_Receiving_Schedule %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(Medicine_Received - lag(Medicine_Received, default = first(Medicine_Received)) > 30)) %>%
  mutate(Days_of_Medicine_Available = cumsum(Days_of_Medicine_Received) - as.integer(Medicine_Received - first(Medicine_Received))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)

#  Medicine_Received Days_of_Medicine_Received Days_of_Medicine_Available
#  <date>                                <dbl>                      <dbl>
#1 2019-01-01                               30                         30
#2 2019-01-20                               30                         41
#3 2019-02-01                               30                         59
#4 2019-06-01                               30                         30
#5 2019-06-15                               30                         46
```

Comment: It's a really good thought, thank you for sharing it.  But, let's hypothesize for the minute that the answer is no - that we don't have the luxury of declaring that after x days we can reset the calculation and would have to look at the entire history.   Is there a way to look at the whole history to judge whether the patient was 'overdue' at some points?